# Use of GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql

QUESTION: Which release_year had the most language diversity?

HINT: Most language diversity" can be interpreted as COUNT(DISTINCT ___).

| id | title | release_year | country | duration | language | certification | gross | budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Intolerance: Love's Struggle Throughout the Ages | 1916 | USA | 123 | null | not rated | null | 385907 |
| 2 | Over the Hill to the Poorhouse | 1915 | Germany | 523 | german | rated | null | 385907 |

These are the fields given. How can I get the release_year in which there is the maximum language diversity?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT release_year)
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        release_year,
        COUNT(DISTINCT language) cnt
    FROM films
    GROUP BY release_year
) t1
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: "release_year in which there is the maximum language diversity" ?

Comment: With this edit (done by @Jaydip) it's starting to make sense...

Comment: Yeah, language is the column, my bad.